# Why does exchange coupling lead to subgap states in superconductors?

Tags: superconductivity

Citing from [Spin-orbital Yu-Shiba-Rusinov states in single Kondo molecular magnet](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-34187-8), the introduction starts by saying that the exchange coupling between magnetic impurities and Bogoliubov quasiparticles of a superconductor leads to low-energy bound states inside the superconducting gap known as Yu-Shiba-Rusinov (YSR) states.

But why is this the case? I understand a magnetic impurity is a spin, and that quasiparticles are also spinful, so that they essentially have Pauli repulsion as explained in the wikipedia article on [exchange interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction). So it makes sense that there is an interaction between the quasiparticles and the impurity. But why does this lead to a bound state, which is formed by a combination of quasiparticle excitations and the magnetic moment? Why does the superconductor not just stay in its ground state, and leave the magnetic impurity as an unscreened doublet?

Is there somehow a large energy penalty from the doublet state, that outweighs the $\Delta$ (superconducting gap) energy cost of exciting quasiparticles?